# How to set unique TextView text color through Android Theme when multiple Themes are available

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a couple of Themes in an app and it works ok. Now I wanted to set a chat bubble text color to color red when user select `BaseTheme.Red`, and text color orange when user select `BaseTheme.Orange` (see code below)

**It´s only the chat bubble text right that I want to be like red for the ´Red´ and Orange for the Orange Theme and all other TextView text color in the app will have default Theme color**.

I try to learn Android Themes and got into trouble setting this chat TextView text color to another color then this global:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
```

I created this: Inside the `BaseTheme.Red`

```
<item name="chatBubbleTextColor">@color/material_red_500</item>
```

and thought I could use it in the TextView xml like

```
android:textColor="?attr/chatBubbleTextColor"
```

but i cannot get it to work maybe it does not work like that?

How can I with the Themes below make this work?

Here is two Themes `Red` and `Orange`:

```
    <!-- Base Theme -->
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Attributes for all APIs -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog.Alert</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/selector_black_pressed</item>
    <!-- Theme for the Preferences -->
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppPreferenceTheme</item>
    <!-- Theme for the pacv_placesAutoCompleteTextV -->
    <item name="pacv_placesAutoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText</item>



<!-- Default App Theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme">
        <!-- API specific attributes 14+ -->
        <item name="selectableRectDrawable">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rect_black</item>
        <item name="selectableRectDrawableInverse">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rect_white</item>
        <item name="selectableRectDrawableColored">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rect_black</item>
        <item name="selectableRoundedRectDrawable">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rounded_rect_black</item>
        <item name="selectableRoundedRectDrawableInverse">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rounded_rect_white</item>
        <item name="selectableRoundedRectDrawableColored">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rounded_rect_black</item>
    </style>



    <!-- Orange App Theme -->
    <style name="BaseTheme.Orange" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- Attributes for all APIs -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_orange_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_orange_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_orange_a700</item>
        <item name="dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog.Orange</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog.Alert.Orange</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/material_orange_300</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Orange" parent="BaseTheme.Orange">
        <!-- API specific attributes 14+ -->
        <item name="selectableRectDrawableColored">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rect_orange</item>
        <item name="selectableRoundedRectDrawableColored">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rounded_rect_orange</item>

        <!-- Add your custom overall styles here -->
    </style>




    <!-- Red App Theme -->
    <style name="BaseTheme.Red" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- Attributes for all APIs -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_red_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_red_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_red_a700</item>
        <item name="dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog.Red</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog.Alert.Red</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/material_red_300</item>
        <!-- Chat bubble attribute not working-->
        <item name="chatBubbleTextColor">@color/material_red_500</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Red" parent="BaseTheme.Red">
        <!-- API specific attributes 14+ -->
        <item name="selectableRectDrawableColored">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rect_red</item>
        <item name="selectableRoundedRectDrawableColored">@drawable/state_list_selectable_rounded_rect_red</item>

        <!-- Add your custom overall styles here -->
    </style>
```

Comment: I have one question why do you change the entire theme instead of changing the text color by something like this? `<color name="errorColor">#f00</color>

textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor));`

Comment: When you do like you say setting color like this `textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorC‌​olor));`  that means that text color will be the same for all Themes. I don't understand what you say with: " I have one question why do you change the entire theme"

Comment: are you going to set multiple theme to one textview at the same time? when you set a color text for one particular textview does it apply to other views?

Comment: My suggestion is you could study this [Android-Material-Themes-Demo](https://github.com/StevenByle/Android-Material-Themes-Demo) to understand what my question is about

Comment: can't you define a style just for your chat bubble and set the textcolor there? For example, by using a style, you can take this layout XML:

`<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="@string/hello" />`
And turn it into this:

`<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />`

Comment: Thanks but how do you suggest that the `"@style/CodeFont"` should be applied? In my app user can switch between Them Red and Theme Orange right,  so the `CodeFont` must resist inside both Themes Red and Orange. Please answer my question and will accept it if it solve this problem

Comment: define a third theme say RedCustom and in that define style for the textcolor you want and set this theme only for your bubble chat. the rest of your appearence would be the same like you wanted.  **It´s only the chat bubble text right that I want to be like red for the ´Red´ Theme and all other TextView text color in the app will have default Theme color.**

Comment: I dont think you understand, User can switch Theme!! and Doing it like that and when user switch to Orange Theme the chat bubble will have the Red textcolor not Orange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135355/discussion-between-mehran-zamani-and-erik-hellberg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703757/android-themes-defining-colours-in-custom-themes)

Basically, it goes like this:

In the file attr.xml, I define this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="ChatBubbleBackGroundColor" format="reference|color" />
    <attr name="ChatBubbleTextColor" format="reference|color" />
</resources>
```

Next I add to my two BaseTheme:

```
<style name="BaseTheme.Red" parent="AppTheme">
   <item name="ChatBubbleBackGroundColor">@color/material_red_a200</item>
   <item name="ChatBubbleTextColor">@color/material_red_a700</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseTheme.Orange" parent="AppTheme">
   <item name="ChatBubbleBackGroundColor">@color/material_orange_a200</item>
   <item name="ChatBubbleTextColor">@color/material_orange_a700</item>
</style>
```

and finally in my layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quoteTitle"
    android:textColor="?ChatBubbleTextColor"
    android:BackGround="?ChatBubbleBackGroundColor"
    ...
</TextView>
```