# I want to change Tabs background color while I change theme

Tags: android

[image: Day theme][image]

Please check image : In Daily, weekly, monthly, yearly :While Night theme, I want to change color from blue to black
Code:

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/cardbackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_repeat_reminder">

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:clipToPadding="true"
                        app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab_reminder_type"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
                        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
                        app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance">

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                            android:id="@+id/tab_daily"
                            style="@style/tabItem"
                            android:text="@string/tab_daily" />

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                            android:id="@+id/tab_weekly"
                            style="@style/tabItem"
                            android:text="@string/tab_weekly" />

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                            android:id="@+id/tab_monthly"
                            style="@style/tabItem"
                            android:text="@string/tab_monthly" />

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                            android:id="@+id/tab_yearly"
                            style="@style/tabItem"
                            android:text="@string/tab_yearly" />
                    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This line change color:  `app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab_reminder_type"`

I did wrong something. (ciuwdhiueiuhferfhrherbhebrhbhebhbfnwnefdwhdewfewfbewfewnnkndnnewdfewfewnfnwfwnefnewnfnewnfwnefnewnfnwnfwnenfwknefnwjeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefeh)

Selector_tab_reminder_type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
   <!-- <item android:drawable="@color/colorTransparent" android:state_selected="false" />-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" android:state_checkable="true" />

</selector>
```

In that Selected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

unselected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/bg_screen3" />
</shape>
```

Full XML ot this screenshot layout: `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activity.AddReminderTypeActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/toolbarcolor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="@string/title_alarm_type" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/cardbackground"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/repeat"
            android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_repeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/cardbackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_repeat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?attr/cardbackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/cardbackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_repeat_reminder">

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:clipToPadding="true"
                        app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab_reminder_type"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
                        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
                        app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance">

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                            android:id="@+id/tab_daily"
                            style="@style/tabItem"
                            android:text="@string/tab_daily" />

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                            android:id="@+id/tab_weekly"
                            style="@style/tabItem"
                            android:text="@string/tab_weekly" />

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                            android:id="@+id/tab_monthly"
                            style="@style/tabItem"
                            android:text="@string/tab_monthly" />

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                            android:id="@+id/tab_yearly"
                            style="@style/tabItem"
                            android:text="@string/tab_yearly" />
                    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/weekdays_error"
                layout="@layout/row_error_textview2" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="?attr/cardbackground">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_repeat_interval"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/repeat_daily"
                    android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />


                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/cardbackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_repeat_reminder"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_interval_increase"
                            style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="+"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_interval_decrease"
                            style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="-"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="?attr/cardbackground">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_list"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="?attr/iconcolor"
                    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="17dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_end_date"
                    style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:hint="YYYY-MM-DD"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_repeat_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="?attr/cardbackground"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_repeat_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:text="@string/one_times"
                        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/cardbackground"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="0dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_repeat_reminder"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btn_count_increase"
                                style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="+"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                android:textSize="20dp" />

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="1dp"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btn_count_decrease"
                                style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:text="-"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                android:textSize="20dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_days"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/cardbackground"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="?attr/cardbackground">

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggleSunday"
                        style="@style/dayTextColor"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textOff="SU"
                        android:textOn="SU"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggleMonday"
                        style="@style/dayTextColor"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textOff="MO"
                        android:textOn="MO"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggleTuesday"
                        style="@style/dayTextColor"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textOff="TU"
                        android:textOn="TU"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggleWednesday"
                        style="@style/dayTextColor"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textOff="WE"
                        android:textOn="WE"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggleThursday"
                        style="@style/dayTextColor"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textOff="TH"
                        android:textOn="TH"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggleFriday"
                        style="@style/dayTextColor"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textOff="FR"
                        android:textOn="FR"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggleSaturday"
                        style="@style/dayTextColor"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textOff="SA"
                        android:textOn="SA"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhiteTransparent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Comment: check if this similar solution helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/12704879/8762338

Comment: @Astha I tried, but without selector it's not possible, I think

Comment: @Astha Can you please help me more?

Comment: Ofcourse use selector but try using ?introColor to setColor as shown in the above link. Check if it helps

Comment: I tried, but border of this  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout> layout goes

Comment: Can you post the changes and the UI as the outcome of those changes?